# Salesforce Assignment checker claiming the output from my method is wrong when it's not

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller, bug, help

Trying to finish the final assignment for the Visualforce Basics,

**Create & Use Custom Controllers** after checking the challenge it says as

```
"The method 'getNewCases' isn't working as expected. Either the method 
doesn't exist or it doesn't return the expected list of cases"
```

I double checked the output by debugging/executing in the console, checking the preview page and even creating a custom list view for new cases to compare it to and surely enough, they match up as shown in the screenshot below.

Any idea why the assignment checker is disagreeing ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Removing **Static** Keywork from your method `getNewCases`

Comment: Thanks Aman that did it. Would've been nice if they mentioned the method shouldn't be static but oh well, cheers for the help!